# Appending elements in a list using for Loop

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I want to append elements in a list using a  `for loop`. This is the code:

```
    outdoor_temp_list = []
    indoor_temp_list = []
    energy_cons_list = []
    outdoor_temp_list.append(30+i)
    indoor_temp_list.append(20+i)
    energy_cons_list.append(200+i)
```

However, it is not appending in each iteration (30, 31, 32, 33, ...), but this the output:
`[34] [24] [204]`
I did not understand how it is working, I would appreciate any help!

Comment: post full codes,

Comment: Can you post the complete code including the outer for loop.Maybe you are re initializing the list every time inside the loop.

Comment: Welcome, Jenny. This question will need a more complete example. E.g. if the current code is the body of a loop, then it's resetting the variables to empty lists each time string the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define list outside.other wise if you are running the code like

```
for i in range(5):
    outdoor_temp_list = []
    indoor_temp_list = []
    energy_cons_list = []
    outdoor_temp_list.append(30 + i)
    indoor_temp_list.append(20 + i)
    energy_cons_list.append(200 + i)
print(outdoor_temp_list,indoor_temp_list,energy_cons_list)
```

you will get output only for the last iteration. because during each iteration you are initializing it by `[]`

```
[34] [24] [204]
```

so you have to initialize it before the for loop

```
outdoor_temp_list = []
indoor_temp_list = []
energy_cons_list = []
for i in range(5):
    outdoor_temp_list.append(30 + i)
    indoor_temp_list.append(20 + i)
    energy_cons_list.append(200 + i)
print(outdoor_temp_list,indoor_temp_list,energy_cons_list)
```

then you will get the desire output like

```
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34] [20, 21, 22, 23, 24] [200, 201, 202, 203, 204]
```